# What are grammar name of causative verbs that don't have "have, get, make or let"?

Tags: parts-of-speech, causatives

As causative verb: I am going to have my friend be suprised.

???: I am going to *astonish* my friend

What are difference between verb *"astonish"* and verb *"be suprised"*? What is  its name in grammar?

Comment: Do you mean, "I'm going to surprise my friend," vs., "I am going to let my friend be surprised"?

Comment: I do not understand the question.

Comment: [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causative) calls such words _lexical causatives_. But that is not a customary phrase (or category) in English grammar as far as I know.

Comment: Both astonish and surprise are verbs. Astonish is simply, "to surprise someone very much" (Ref: Oxford English Learners Dict. online). A synonym for astonish would be amaze. Therefore, by definition, the difference between astonish and surprise is astonish just a much higher degree of surprise.  The list of English causative verbs are have, get, make, let, and help. The only one missing from your list above is help. I hope this answers your question.

Comment: @BenjaminHarman (also Lambie and Steve B053) Sorry, ı have given nonsense examples. "Die" and "Kill" are a better examples.

Comment: "Die" and "kill" are better examples of what? You are not making your question any clearer but only making it even more incomprehensible.

Comment: @JamesK  No, I've found what ı want; it's lexical causatives. Thanks again

Comment: @BenjaminHarman  Sorry for this, but "lexical causative" was what ı want.

Comment: Please use a capital I for the pronoun I in English.

Answer (score 0):

I've found what ı want; it's lexical causative. "Astonish" is a lexical causative".

Comment: Convertting a comment.  Not sure about the correctness of this answer.